# How to adjust input type select size in contact from 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm create a contact form and give 100% to all fields but select option is not working on 100% properly it set when I give 131% to it. How I can solve this problem.[image: Select box image]

Comment: check whether padding had been applied. Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by Adding 100% !important 
    Or
    You can check is there any max-width is involved with it or not.

```
Use max-width: 100% !important; 
min-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;

Check it and let me know.
```

Comment: No still size is short

Comment: add css of select box to display:flex; flex:100%;